# postfix keep original sender ip on mail server delivery

Tags: postfix, email-server, forwarding

I have Proxmox Mail Gateway facing internet with port 25.
When the email is recieved it is read and then forwarded to mail server.
On my mail server i see that all the emails are going from this PGM ip address.
Is it possible to rewrite some setting in postfix,etc... on PMG so that the original senders IP is kept and my email server will see the senders IP and not the PMG IP?

Thank you

P.S. I asked on proxmox forum they forwarded me on this page
http://www.postfix.org/XFORWARD_README.html
But i am still not able to figure it out.

Comment: Why did they give you that URL? Do they mean that PMG will send XFORWARD data to your mail server?

Comment: Hi, I can't answer you that. This was the persons post where he stated that it should provide that functionality:      haven't needed this myself - but check the xforward howto of postfix if you indeed want this functionality - that should provide a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so that the original senders IP is kept and my email server will see the senders IP

Your email server will see (but not by default, act on) the trace headers (`Received:`) anyway. The only reason you would want to change its behaviour using either option would be if that alone does not suffice.

You should detail *in what software and for which purposes* your email server needs a different view of the client data, only then you can decide on the features best suited to serve that requirement.

> and not the PMG IP

Removing trace information from mails is generally unwise, and rarely necessary. If you really do need that, it will also factor into the decision on how to configure the server.

---

You can allow transmission of client information via XCLIENT or XFORWARD with these basic steps:

1. Tell your receiving server (here: postfix) announce support for and trust the information provided by the forwarder
2. Tell your mail forwarder (here: PMG) to send the data

Part one is done using the `smtpd_authorized_xclient_hosts` or `smtpd_authorized_xforward_hosts` options. Which one of those you need depends on what additional services attached to your Postfix server are processing that data.

Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1078753/edit) your question to provide the current forwarder configuration, then I may be able to point you to the relevant setting name.

Comment: Hi, as you said "Removing trace information from mails is generally unwise." I will keep it seperated then. In the near future i will be moving my mail server to different software.So no need to spend time on this one. If i would need it in the future, will write. Thank you!!!